# Formatting numbers with thousand separators

Tags: ocaml, number-formatting, ocaml-core

Is there anything in the standard library or in Core that I can use to format integers with thousand separators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, nothing, expect that you can use the `%a` format specifier and provide your own pretty-printer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `%#d` format to print an integer using underscores as separators (following OCaml lexical conventions):

```
# Printf.sprintf "=> %#d" 1000000;;
- : string = "=> 1_000_000"
```

And then replace underscores with commas:

```
# Printf.sprintf "=> %#d" 1000000 |> String.map (function '_' -> ',' | char -> char);;
- : string = "=> 1,000,000"
```